# form_for giving error for the url parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller called RegistrationController. The routes are defined like this:

```
 get "registration/index"
  get "registration/create"
  get "registration/new"
```

The new.erb contains the following line:

```
<%= form_for :registration, url:registration/create do |f| %>
```

the above line is not working and giving the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `registration' for #<#<Class:0x007fd382a810d0>:0x007fd38296dd38>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a string for the url instead, so ruby doesn't interpret it as a method:

```
<%= form_for :user, url: 'registration/create' do |f| %>
```

Comment: @johndoe Could you post your `Registration` model in your question?

Comment: Okay so this is confusing. My model name is User so should I type form_for :user ???

Comment: @johndoe Yes, you want to name the form after the model it is for.

Comment: So, if the controller name is RegistrationsController can I name and use my model called User in RegistrationsController

Comment: @johndoe Sure! Normally the controller is named after the model it manipulates, but in no way does that have to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

What do you have in Config/Routes ?
Do you have the equivalent of

```
resources :registration, only: [:new, :create, :index]
```